# Is it possible to give only view permission for Jenkins monitoring-plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins

We have the monitoring-plugin installed:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/monitoring-plugin

is there a way to give only view permissions once it is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No :). please see Jenkins issue 14750:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14750